What are the pros but particularly the cons, of using "heavy hands" (carrying along a couple small dumbbells) whilst walking?
I walk quite vigorously for about 90 mins 7/7 days. (I don't do any weight lifting or other training.)
For no particular reason, I grabbed two 5 lb dumbbells from the sports store, and I carry those, one in each hand, as I walk, ie for the entire 90 mins or so.
Is there actually any downside to this?
It seems to be a good thing as it makes you "tighten up and straighten up" which perhaps helps with posture and (I guess?) the muscles sort of behind your shoulders.
(I notice the effect is drastically different if you just hang your arms naturally, versus, if you bring them up near your chest and sort of punch 1-2-1-2 in step with your legs swinging; maybe one or the other is no good, I don't know.)
Fill me in, experts!

Bounty here, surprised no science so far!

Pros:

Increased total weight which increases calories expended (by a very small, but measurable amount).
Increased total weight which strengthens ability to walk.
Strengthens grip ability and endurance

Cons:

Possible increased strain on shoulder, forearms, and hands. May or may not be detrimental based on the individual. If you start feeling unbearable uncomfort, then you can just stop using dumbbells for a walk or two and rest your arms.
Possible slight alteration of walking gait. Can be somewhat detrimental for someone used to walking a certain way for long distances.
Kind of annoying.  No free hands when you need it.

At 5 lbs (10 lbs total), you probably won't notice the pros or the cons that much. There will be a very small, passive benefit to walking with dumbbells. Not something that you'd notice day-to-day, but 6 months down the line you'd probably have a noticeably stronger walking stride then you would otherwise.
Increasing the weight would increase the effects of both pros and cons. If you're happy with the 5 lb dumbbells then I would say just keep at it.

unreal.  I think the key takeaway is "unlikely any harm", great.  you know what, when walking with them I've also tried doing random stretching-like, swinging them around motions as I go. Anything I can think of, such as: "punching" with them, at chest height in step with my steps; big slow windmills; hanging them in my hands behind my back and lifting; etc. It does seem to invigorate the walking, perhaps using a few more calories.  (I'm unable to jog ATM, sticking to long walks.)

I mean I say "unlikely to harm" because I don't like speaking in absolutes.  Considering everything you've said, I don't think you'd have any problems with them.

Sent a small bounty as thanks, TY

@Fattie Thank you!
